# Azure Emulator - when using node.js, where is the console log written?

Tags: azure

I am using Azure node js  emulator.

from power shell, I was able to start the :

```
start-AzureEmulator.
```

in my server.js, I have :

```
console.log();
```

I dont see these logs written on power shell .
where are  these console logs written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default logs are written to a logs folder within your project folder. You can also view the logs realtime by right clicking on the emulator taskbar icon and then viewing the emulator ui.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Node Inspector (Chrome/Safari/FireFox)

More here ["Using node-inspector to debug node.js applications including on Windows (and using ryppi for modules)"](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2011/10/13/using-node-inspector-to-debug-node-js-applications-including-on-windows-and-using-ryppi-for-modules/)

There might be other simpler ways but this should work.